# How can I list all the folders an Outlook Mail Item is stored in using VBA?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba

I've imported my Gmail into Outlook using IMAP and am now running some VBA reporting scripts.  Gmail labels have been converted to folders in Outlook and mail items with multiple labels from Gmail seem to be stored in multiple folders in Outlook.  I'm attempting to return the mailitem.parent property but it only lists the active mail item parent.  Ie.  If I'm searching in the "Testing Categories" folder, it returns "Testing Categories" only, even if those messages are also in Inbox and other folders.

```
For Each olItem In olFolder.Items
On Error Resume Next
If olItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
Set olMail = olItem
Debug.Print olMail.Parent
...
```

Comment: IMAP does not have local folders?!? That happened with POP3.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I thought I read that as well but I know the account settings were IMAP and that the messages *appear* to be stored in multiple folders in Outlook corresponding to their gmail labels.  Maybe this is an edition issue?

Answer (score 2):

Gmail's IMAP is quite complex. Since Gmail doesn't support folders (as IMAP requires), it mimics folders by providing label names to email clients (like Outlook). When you have several labels on email, it actually provides a copy of email message for each IMAPI "folder". From Outlook point of view, and any other IMAP client these messages are different. If you'll delete the email in one of these "folders", Gmail will just remove the label from it. And if you're going to modify the email (say, edit subject) in one of "folders", Gmail will create the actual copy of email, you'll see it on gmail.com. The only unique identifier these emails have in common is the PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID MAPI property (http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001F).

So, if you really want to collect all Gmail labels from one particular email, you need to retrieve the http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001F property using PropertyAccessor and then search across all mailbox by this property value to find the matching emails. And even then you may not get all the results because not all Gmail labels may be accessible using IMAP and not all IMAP folders may be syncronized.

Comment: Wow.  Thank you thims!  I was hoping there was some complicated answer and I wasn't just missing something obvious.  I'll play around with this to confirm, but this sounds like the issue for sure.